# Excel table from Outlook: Fill Series directly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have inserted a new table directly from Outlook, and I want to fill series as we would normally do in Excel. Is there any way of doing that **from Outlook itself**? Or simply we have to go back to Excel and fill the table and then Paste it here(or add it as an Object or whatever)?

I tried to use the formula "=INDIRECT("B" & ROW()-1)+1", which worked in Excel(Fill Series-increment by 1 in this case) (in Column B) but not in Outlook(Shows SYNTAX ERROR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done if you insert the table as Excel Object.

Once inserted, you will be able to apply the formulas.

[image: Insert Object]

[image: Use formula]

Comment: Thanks Scorpion, but that table gets embedded as an image(object) and so cells become uneditable after sending.(Receiver can't edit it, as they would do on a normal table while replying). But mainly, formulas work fine while composing mail and thanks for that :)